# PHP Net/SMTP versus Mail

Tags: php

I cannot seem to figure out which is the preferred way to send mail from PHP using PEAR. Half the search results uses Mail.php and a factory method and the other half includes Net/SMTP and uses new Net_SMTP etc etc. Which is archaic and which contemporary?

Comment: Use what you prefer. Swiftmailer is also a good mail library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which is archaic and which contemporary ?

Neither. They are very different ways of sending emails and a lot of the reason for having different methods is to do with how your MTA is configured.